# Lombok @getter not working in src/test/java package

Tags: java, gradle, lombok, java-11

I have upgraded my jdk from 10 to 11 with all the dependencies updated to use the latest versions. When compiling using gradle wrapper it is throwing following error

`symbol:   method getId()
TestLombok.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
object.setId(Long.valueOf(getRandomString(5, onlyNumbers)));`

- Gradle Wrapper Distribution version 5.4.1
- JDK 11.0.2
- Mac Machine
- Lombok 1.18.8

I have tried with various versions of lombok but not able to solve the issue

- 1.18.8
- 1.18.4

previously I was using lombok 1.18.2 and annotationprocessor 1.18.2

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

  @JsonProperty("id")
  public Long id;
}
```

I expect the issues to be fixed with gradle5.x.x version but still the issue persists. Let me know if we have any issue using gradle wrapper version. Following is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
    }
}


apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"

group = "com.demo"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8")
    compile("org.mockito:mockito-core:" + mockitoVersion)
    test.useJUnitPlatform()
    annotationProcessor ('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8')
    testCompileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8")

}
```

Comment: Can you add your gradle file?

Comment: What is yours IDE? Some IDEs have their own lombok plugins which must be upgraded in order to work with. AFAIK Java 11 is supported after `1.18.4` but that depends if the plugin supports it as well.

Comment: Also, can you show us the class `TestLombok`?

Comment: I have added gradle file

Comment: I have not included any plugin explicitly

Comment: Has your problem been solved by any of the answers? If yes, go ahead and accept it. If not, report what problem you’re having.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just reproduced the same issue which you faced, my gradle version is

> Gradle Version : 5.4.1

To resolve this, in reference to the Lombok doc (https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle) I changed the dependency as below.

```
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
```

You could take look at this https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1945 for more info

Comment: JDK version is 11.0.2. In the ticket it is 11.0.1

Comment: Did you give it a try? coz I think gradle causes this issue not JDK. I have tried the same with gradle lower version `4.10.3` it worked but not in `5.x.x` version

Comment: It worked with 4.10.3 Any workaround to make it work with 5.x.x

Comment: `compileOnly` & `annotationProcessor` should work  with 5.x.x

Comment: I have tried it with both compileOnly & annotationProcessor, still the issue persists

Comment: Any update on this issue. I have upgraded my gradle to 5.6 version still the problem persists

Answer (score 17):

For Lombok annotations in test source sets, you need to add Lombok to two dependency configurations:

```
testCompileOnly '...'
testAnnotationProcessor '...'
```

In the same way as `compileOnly` and `annotationProcessor` the first one makes the annotations available to the code and the second one activates annotation processing during compilation.

Comment: I have checked with this solution also still the issue persists

Answer (score 2):

You didn’t post your `build.gradle` but I’m guessing you declared Lombok dependency as `compileOnly`, which only applies to main code. Also declare it as `testCompileOnly`.

Comment: @ManishChandraRanga If using Gradle 5, you also need annotation processor. See https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle

Answer (score 2):

Finally able to solve this issue by upgrading the gradle version to 5.6 and also testCompileOnly '...'
testAnnotationProcessor '...'

by adding the above two things in build.gradle file